# Download all dpkg dependencies for a package

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I need to use apt-offline on a debian system which is offline all the time. At the moment this package is not installed so I want to download all dependencies for it and install it offline from a usb drive. Is there any tool to put all dependencies inside a folder for a given package?

Answer (score 0):

To install `apt-offline` offline you should download the `.deb` file from debian-package

There is an example on debian stretch:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt-offline/apt-offline_1.7.2_all.deb
dpkg -i apt-offline_1.7.2_all.deb
```

After running the `dpkg` command you will show an error listing the missing dependencies (a sample output from an updated system):

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-offline:
apt-offline depends on python-magic; however:
Package python-magic is not installed.
```

The missing dependencies can installed through `dpkg` after getting the `.deb` file from the official website by [**searching**](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages)